# Application font size dosn't change

Tags: android

I'm working on an application that can change the device font size. When I change the font size from my application, the change applies to the whole device and other applications but not itself. I  haven't set font sizes in **dp**. What causes this problem?

Comment: you probably need to recreate the activity for the changes to take effect

Comment: But how other applications affected automatically?

Comment: how do you check that? by opening them? Then they just read new configuration from start. HAve you tried restarting your app?

Comment: Yes, I create a test application only with a TextView and font-size also affected on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. I had used

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
> ```

changed its version to 1.0.2 and it solved.
I reported this issue to google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151376

Comment: Seems to be fixed in version `1.2.0-rc01`

Answer (score 0):

Check your activity tag inside AndroidManifest.xml

if if has something similar to `android:configChanges="fontScale"` remove it.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale">
```

Comment: No, There isn't.